# How to cURL Put in Java

Tags: java, linux, http, curl, artifactory

Looking for an easy way to replicate the following Linux cUrl command in java:

I need to upload the file "/home/myNewFile.txt" via HTTP / Curl to a Http server (which in this case is artifact or)

`curl -u myUser:myP455w0rd! -X PUT "http://localhost:8081/artifactory/my-repository/my/new/artifact/directory/file.txt" -T /home/myNewFile.txt`

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you tried anything?  Have you ever used the java.net.HttpURLConnection class before?

Comment: tried using java.net.URL / URLConnection but I'm not entirely sure how to translate the arguments like-u, -X, -T

Comment: Artifactory has a java client which can be useful for you
take a look at:
https://github.com/JFrogDev/artifactory-client-java

Comment: @TamirHadad thats awesome and pretty much exactly what I need. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 3):

First, cast your URLConnection to an HttpURLConnection.

- For curl’s -X option, use [setRequestMethod](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/net/HttpURLConnection.html#setRequestMethod-java.lang.String-).
- For curl’s -T option, use [setDoOutput(true)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/net/URLConnection.html#setDoOutput-boolean-), [getOutputStream()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/net/URLConnection.html#getOutputStream--), and [Files.copy](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#copy-java.nio.file.Path-java.io.OutputStream-).
- For curl’s -u option, set the `Authorization` [request header](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/net/URLConnection.html#setRequestProperty-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-) to `"Basic "` (including the space) followed by the [base 64 encoded](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Base64.html#getEncoder--) form of `user + ":" + password`.  This is the Basic Authentication Scheme described in the [RFC 2616: HTTP 1.1](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616#section-14.8) specification and [RFC 2617: HTTP Authentication](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2617#section-2).

In summary, the code would look like this:

```
URL url = new URL("http://localhost:8081/artifactory/my-repository/my/new/artifact/directory/file.txt");

HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

String auth = user + ":" + password;
conn.setRequestProperty("Authorization", "Basic " +
    Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(
        auth.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8)));

conn.setRequestMethod("PUT");
conn.setDoOutput(true);
try (OutputStream out = conn.getOutputStream()) {
    Files.copy(Paths.get("/home/myNewFile.txt"), out));
}
```

Comment: I try this but do not work. My Artyfactory version is `EnterpriseX license 7.12.6 rev 71206900` I use Java 8.

Comment: I have `404 Not Found` with th same url of my curl

Answer (score 0):

I am not advocating that this is the correct way to do things, but you could execute the command line statement as is directly from your java file.

Here is a snippet of code from a program I wrote that executes a php script (using a linux commandline statement) from within a java program I wrote.

```
public void executeCommand(String command)
{
    if(command.equals("send_SMS"))
    {
        try
        {
            //execute PHP script that calls Twilio.com to sent SMS text message.
            Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("php send-sms.php\n");
        }
        catch(IOException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

This worked for me.

Check out the API for the Process and Runtime classes here:

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Process.html

and

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html

Comment: OK, really??  An anonymous down vote?  Someone asked for help, and I provided one possible, and valid, answer.

Comment: This may be due to the fact that your answer is only very remotely related to OP's question. Perhaps you provided an answer for a different one?

Comment: Thanks for that. problem is I would need to keep it OS independent (I didnt down vote you btw)

Comment: Thanks your suggestion to call bash with curl helped me figure out what was going wrong with my HttpUrlConnection and PUT ... took me hours to do in Java.