# Using Java to run this CURL command in an automated test

Tags: java, http, curl

I'm new to Java and I need to send a CURL command to BrowserStack, saying that my automated test has failed. I have the following CURL command that I must run:

```
curl -u "XXX:YYY" -X PUT -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d "{\"status\":\"failed\", \"reason\":\"\"}" https://api.browserstack.com/automate/sessions/ZZZ.json
```

*P.S: XXX and YYY redacted due to work*

The only thing is that I need is to replace ZZZ with a variable in this command, so let's say I have this so far:

```
void sendCurlCommand(){

    String sessionId = "123ABC";

    // code to send this curl command here

}
```

I tried several solutions here in StackOverflow, but all the ones I tried, they run and give no errors at all, but nothing happens on BrowserStack side, so I can't debug what's happening. If I run this exact command on my Linux terminal, it works like a charm.

Comment: You should use a Java HTTP client, and translate the curl call into it. What exactly did you try?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42260471/6311045)

Comment: What version of Java are you using?  The java.net.http package is best suited to this, if you’re using Java 11 or later.

Comment: @VGR if I run "java -version" I get this: openjdk version "1.8.0_222"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_222-8u222-b10-1ubuntu1~18.04.1-b10)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.222-b10, mixed mode)

Comment: @cricket_007 one of the simplest methods I tried was this one (example): String command = "curl -X POST https://postman-echo.com/post --data foo1=bar1&foo2=bar2"; 
Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command); ... but nothing happens, no error, no logs, nothing

Comment: Are you expecting any output from the call?

Comment: @VGR nope, no outputs, I just need to run this curl so my test on browserstack is changed from passed to fail, but this I'll check on the browserstack page, I don't need any output in the java

Comment: I still don't understand why you're using `Runtime` instead of `HttpUrlConnection` or another library like OkHttp

Comment: @cricket_007 that's what I'm asking here, for a way to run this command, it doesn't need to use `Runtime`, it was just an example I tried and failed

Comment: Did you try the code in the second comment above?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could finally fail my testing using CURL. I use the following dependency on Maven:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
    <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
    <version>4.3.6</version>
</dependency>
```

And I used the following code:

```
URI uri = new URI("https://XXX:YYY@api.browserstack.com/automate/sessions/"
        + sessionId + ".json");
HttpPut putRequest = new HttpPut(uri);

ArrayList<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
nameValuePairs.add((new BasicNameValuePair("status", "failed")));
nameValuePairs.add((new BasicNameValuePair("reason", "")));
putRequest.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));

HttpClientBuilder.create().build().execute(putRequest);
```